# Set Property Value of one node to another Node Cypher Query (neo4j)

Tags: neo4j

I wanted to set the property  `pcrT` in `LIKE` using the `crT` of `POST` (`r.pcrT = p.crT`) by the below query.But its not working.Its not creating property `pcrT` in `LIKE`.

```
     MATCH  (n:USER{id:"372759437051554"}),(p:POST{id:"374210538678640"})
        WHERE NOT (n)-[:POSTED]-(p) 
        MERGE (n)-[r:LIKE]-(p) ON 
        CREATE SET p.fcount = p.fcount + 1,
                   r.lat = 11.2,
                   r.lon = 11.2,
                   r.crT = timestamp(),
                   r.pcrT = p.crT
                   RETURN p,r;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine.It contains already a `LIKE` relationship so it's not creating again that relationship